# How to print a string in c language for like 10 seconds?

Tags: c

```
while(1) {
printf("Hello World");
}
```

We know this would keep on printing the **Hello World** string for infinite times. My goal is to print this for 10 seconds. I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    int ticks = clock();
    while(ticks <= 10000000000) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It still goes for an infinite time. Please let me where did I made the mistake.

Comment: Your program is flawed in two ways: First of all it's not guaranteed that `clock` return a zero-based value; Secondly you never modify `ticks` inside the loop, it will never get an updated value. And it's not even guaranteed to return a wall-clock time.

Comment: `clock_t end_time = clock() + 10*CLOCKS_PER_SEC; while(clock() < end_time) { ... }` - but is `clock()` really the clock you want to use? "_clock() - an approximation of processor time used by the program_"

Comment: As a way to solve your problem, if you get the time before the loop, and the difference between the start time and the current time is equal or larger than ten seconds then end the loop.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mainly just want to print for like 10 seconds. That is it.

Comment: Then perhaps using `time()` would be better. `time_t end_time = time(NULL) + 10; while(time(NULL) < end_time) { ... }`

Comment: You need to consider `clock()` overflows! So `while(clock() < end_time)` is not guaranteed to work in any case. If e.g. `clock() - start_time` will turn out smaller than zero, the datatype maximum needs to be added to the negative value to get the correct time difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `time()`

Save the start time in one variable. Have another variable with the current time and keep printing until the difference is what you want.

Like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t start = time(NULL);     // Get start time
    time_t current = start;
    while(current - start < 10) {  // Check difference
        printf("Hello World\n");
        // sleep(1);               // To limit amount of output if needed
        current = time(NULL);      // Update current time
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I mainly just want to print for like 10 seconds

Then I suggest using the standard [`time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t end_time = time(NULL) + 10; // calculate the end time

    while(time(NULL) < end_time) { // loop until the end time is reached
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the idea of calculating end-time

Comment: @4386427 Thanks.  Yeah, it keeps the calculations down but I assume a good optimizer would fix it any way one prefers it.

Comment: Probably... But the next time I need something like this, I use your approach instead of mine. 

Answer (score 0):

This code will print the string, then issue a `'\r'` to return the cursor to the left of the terminal, then issue a `"\033[K"` to erase from the cursor to the end of the line, and a `'\n'` to end the program on a new line (you can avoid this, as the cursor is already in an empty line)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world ");
    fflush(stdout); /* force a write(2) to output the string to the terminal */
    sleep(10);
    printf("\r\033[K\n"); /* carry return, escape to erase from the
                            * cursor to the end of the screen, and new
                            * line */
    return 0;
}
```